# How to get the value of a textbox from sa MDI form Groupbox?

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, mdichild, mdiparent

I'm new to vb.net and always searching for solution. My forms involved are **MainMenu, poCustom, and rdlcForm**. All are working well until I got a new look with **MDI Forms**.

My "New" MainMenu are now containing the poCustom into a Groupbox. Which I searched the code as

```
    For Each f As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If TypeOf f Is poCustom Then
            f.Activate()
            Return
        End If
    Next

    Dim ch As New poCustom
    ch.TopLevel = False
    ch.Visible = True

    ch.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    Dim leftStart As Integer = 1220 - (ch.Width + (SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width * 2))
    Dim topStart As Integer = 670 - (ch.Height + (SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height * 2))

    ch.Location = New Point(leftStart, topStart)

    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(ch)
```

**Problem:** The rdlcForm(report) cannot get the value of textboxes in poCustom form. Code below:

```
 Private Sub rptPOView2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim rptParam1(11) As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
    rptParam1(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptDate", poCustom.Label1.Text)
    rptParam1(1) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptREF", poCustom.Label5.Text)
    rptParam1(2) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptCompany", poCustom.CompanyName.Text)
    rptParam1(3) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptQTY", poCustom.txBoxQTY.Text)
    rptParam1(4) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptUOM", poCustom.txBoxUOM.Text)
    rptParam1(5) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptDesciption", poCustom.txBoxDesc.Text)
    rptParam1(6) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptUnit", poCustom.txBoxUnit.Text)
    rptParam1(7) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptTotal", poCustom.txBoxTotal.Text)
    rptParam1(8) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptSubTotal", poCustom.Label25.Text)
    rptParam1(9) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptVAT", poCustom.Label26.Text)
    rptParam1(10) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptTotalAmount", poCustom.Label27.Text)
    rptParam1(11) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("rptRequest", poCustom.Label30.Text)

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParam1)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    TextBox1.Text = poCustom.CompanyName.Text
End Sub
```

Which happens to work without using MDI Forms. I would like to know the cause of the problem for future use. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `poCustom`? And shouldnt you use `POForm` instead of `poCustom` such as `ReportParameter("rptDate", POForm.Label1.Text)`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I got two forms for Purchase Order, the poDefault and poCustom. I'll update my question sorry.

Comment: I think you are using different instances of poCustom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different instances of `poCustom`. `ch` is the first, and you populate its textboxes. But on the `rptPOView2_Load` event, you are using the other instance, which contains textboxes that has no value yet. One way to fix the problem is to use `poCustom` itself and not `ch`.

```
poCustom.TopLevel  = False
poCustom.Visible = True

poCustom.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
Dim leftStart As Integer = 1220 - (ch.Width + (SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width * 2))
Dim topStart As Integer = 670 - (ch.Height + (SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height * 2))

poCustom.Location = New Point(leftStart, topStart)

GroupBox1.Controls.Add(poCustom)
```